# js. Стрелочная функция и this

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,

раньше я писал так:

```js
myElem.onfocus = function () {
  magicWithMyElem(this);
}
```

Теперь, узнав как посокращать код с функциональными выражениями, везде исправил на:

```js
myElem.onfocus = () => {
  magicWithMyElem(this);
}
```

Столкнулся с тем, что раньше в this было myElem, а теперь this возвращает window

Подскажите что делать

Comment: Вернуть все назад. В первом варианте в `this` подставляется объект, от которого вызвана функция, во втором - объект в методе которого было вызвано присваивание `myElem.onfocus = ...`

Comment: Контекст вызова потерян, се ля ви. Сегодня сам читал про это главу на learn.javascript.ru. Советую обратиться туда и освежить голову.

Comment: И не на том ты экономишь в js, ох не на том) С таким лучше не заниматься хаками, а следовать стандартам.

Comment: И да, справедливости ради, в первом случае `this` не всегда будет равен `myElem`: `myElem.onfocus.apply(window)`

Comment: @n0rd, а что этот пример должен показать? Конечно this и не будет равен, контекст же самостоятельно был передан window. Но использовать в функциях (даже анонимных) this - нормальная практика. Нужно просто понимать, на какое дело создаются функции.

Comment: @VostokSisters, а на чем экономить в js ?

Comment: @StanislavSagan на конструкторах :DDD Но честно говоря, не приведу масштабного примера, потому что опыта мало. Но контекст вызова функции - штука сложная, играться с ней не лучшее решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется [стрелочная функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
Она отличается от обычной рядом особенностей:

- Нет своего `this`, `arguments` (берётся от предка, Вы исполняете код в глобальном скоупе, а там `this` указывает на `window`).
- Не может быть генератором.
- Нет возможности вызова с `new`.

Comment: Нормально ли будет подставлять вместо this элемент из события event ? Как лучше поступать?

Comment: @StanislavSagan, нормально или нет - это смотря от Вашей общей архитектуры. Я бы не использовал стрелки там, где нужен `this` или особенности "старших" функций. Разница-то в количестве букв на `function` :)